# Magento 2.4.1 Showing an Error No alive node found in you cluster while running upgrade Command

Tags: magento2.4.1

When I try to run upgrade and reindex Command on terminal it's showing an error No alive node found in you cluster, I am not able to set up elasticsearch Configuration on backend showing an same error. sudo command also not working it's showing an command not found. I have attached snap of the error for you reference.

[image: Error showing on terminal while running upgrade cmd]

[image: Backend Configuration Error testing]

Answer (score 0):

It means your elasticsearch is not running. make sure elasticsearch service is started before running command.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I facing an error as command not found on terminal, i have run the cmd on root file.

Comment: have u installed elasticsearch?

Comment: yes i have installed elasticsearch

Comment: then your server should always enabled. this error will occur if elasticsearch is not enable on your computer/server

Answer (score 0):

Check Status of Elasticsearch

```
service elasticsearch status
```

if elasticsearch is status is inactive try starting using

```
service elasticsearch status
```

if you are facing issue while starting elasticsearch

```
vi /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have run the command but it's showing as error on terminal bash: service: command not found

Comment: are you using on windows?

Comment: I have running the command on cpanel using Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

After you open your terminal then 
Please Try these command to start and enable elastic search.

```
systemctl start elasticsearch
systemctl enable elasticsearch
systemctl status elasticsearch

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var pub
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

Then refresh your browser. 
Let me know if you got any issues.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, when i try to run the command it's showing as systemct1 command not found error and also i run adding php before the cmd it's showing Could not open input file  systemctl, can you help me to rectify the issue.

Comment: its not systemct1 but its systemctl  where l for lion.. Please share the screenshot of error also.